# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - Trial Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, trialware

I had a trial of Visual Studio 2010 running, but now I've run out of days. When I try to extend the trial it sends me to the *Ultimate* version for the key extension. I signed up there and everything and got a code, but when I insert it in Visual Studio 2010 it says the code is invalid.

How do I succesfully get a *Professional* trial key extension?

P.S. The site is also in Japanese for me, which makes it even more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the correct key by doing the following:

1. Go to Control Panel -> (Un)Install software;
2. Browse to your Visual Studio 2010 install and click Remove/Change;
3. The Visual Studio Maintenance Mode Wizard will load, wait a little and click next when it's done;
4. On the bottom left of the window you will see a the "Extend Trial" option. When you click this link it will guide you to the correct website. Which is currently: [go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=133426](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=133426)
5. Sign up with your Microsoft account and apply for the trial extension;
6. Wait for the mail Microsoft sent you and use the provided key the extend your trial. (This code should work!)